# How to use SessionState on load balanced Azure virtual machines

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, session-state

I have written a .NET application which I would like to host on Azure, using (at least) two virtual machines, a load balancer and a SQL-server database.

According to [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/managing-session-state-in-windows-azure-what-are-the-options/) page, I have to choose between table storage, SQL Server and Redis cache.

I'd like to go with SQL Server for session storage, because I already have a SQL-server instance. However, when I use the steps with aspnet_regsql.exe I get timeouts. I have also exported the script generated with aspnet_regsql.exe, and then ran it through SSMS, but it returned an insane amount of errors. (link to script and errors posted in first comment)

How am I supposed to use sessionState in Azure with a SQL Server?

Thank you very much!

Comment: [script](https://pastebin.com/P2x8HJvy), [errors](https://pastebin.com/nu8XGarQ)

Comment: I was not allowed to do this, because I need more than 10 points to allow to post two links!

Comment: Mods must have gone crazy. I cannot edit question to include @Joel'-' links as "Links to PasteBin" must be accompanied by code.

Comment: If you look closely at the first 4 errors, you will see that a number of commands used by script are not supported e.g. `USE`. A quick Google search for ".net database session state with azure db" bring up this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-sql-azure-for-session-state/

Comment: Yes, the rules for links are strict unfortunately. But I suppose it keeps the quality high.

Anwyay, thanks for your link. But it is a 7 years old blog post, which no longer contains the adjusted SQL-script!

Comment: What about other links returned by Google? e.g. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/managing-session-state-in-windows-azure-what-are-the-options/

Comment: I've looked at many of them. I actually shared the link you just posted in my original post. Unfortunately, this post is also really old; the links in this post are not up to date anymore :(

Comment: Post version of .NET etc. you are using and do list a links you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I find a related [blog](https://blog.truelime.nl/2016/12/23/setup-sql-server-session-state-for-a-web-farm/) about this, please have try to follow the steps:

> 1.Setup the session state database using the ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool

```
 %Windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe -S MyCluster\Prod -U sa -P topsecret -ssadd -ssype p
```

> 2.Configure the connection string in web.config
>   I strongly reccommend including the application name in the connection string and keeping the connection time out low.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SessionConnectionString"
    connectionString="Data Source=MyCluster\Prod,1234;user=sa;pwd=topsecret;Connect Timeout=10;Application Name=xxxx;Current Language=English" />
</connectionStrings>
```

> 3.Setup the machine key in web.config
>   If you’re running the site on multiple servers or in the cloud, this is a must.

```
<system.web>
   <machineKey xdt:Transform="Insert"
     validationKey="..."
     decryptionKey="..."
     validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
</system.web>
```

> 4.Configure session state in web.config

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState mode="SQLServer"
     sqlConnectionString="SessionConnectionString"
     compressionEnabled="true"
     cookieless="false"
     timeout="20"/>
</system.web>
```